# LMMs: Random effects with categorical variables

Tags: categorical-data, lme4-nlme, glmm

I am setting up LMMs to assess the effect of two interventions on the clinical outcome (Y) over time.

Thus, I have 2 predictors:
group (between-persons, 2 levels: interventions A and B) and
time (within-persons, 4 measurement time points: pre-intervention, post-intervention, follow-up 1, follow-up 2).

Per person and time, there is 1 observation, thus the data looks like this:

```
id    group    time     Y
1     1        1        ...
1     1        2        ...
1     1        3        ...
1     1        4        ...
2     2        1        ...
2     2        2        ...
2     2        3        ...
2     2        4        ...
```

I use R and lme4 to estimate my models. Now importantly, time is a factor, hence a categorical variable, and a fixed effect, because I want lme4 to give me an estimate of Y for every level of time, thus an estimate how Y changed from t1 to t2, from t1 to t3 and from t1 to t4.

However, I also want to estimate random slopes per person, because it is theoretically plausible to assume that there is inter-individual variability in the change of Y over time. Therefore, to my mind, it seems reasonable to include a random effect to account for individual time courses per participant: (1 + time | id). The model would look like:

`Y ~ group + time + (1 + time | id)`

However, lme4 gives an error, because it requires every combination of time*id to have multiple entries. The error message looks like this:

Error: number of observations (=116) <= number of random effects (=116) for term (1 + time | id); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable

Could anybody explain the reasoning behind this to me? I don't understand why it is not possible to estimate individual time courses if there is only 1 observation per time*id combination. Still, the time courses can vary across persons independently of the group, right?

How can I deal with this? Is it possible to estimate the model as I wish, with individual time courses and the fixed effects of time and group, or if not, how should the model be altered to allow me to investigate the intervention effect over time?

Many thanks in advance.